# Trying to scrape email

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape email but it give me `none` these is page link https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/3?view=entry

I am going to the `network tab` and check the `html code` from the but the email doesnot exsist in html code:

```
<div class="contact"><p>Contacter par email : <span id="cloak65106">Cette adresse e-mail est protégée contre les robots spammeurs. Vous devez activer le JavaScript pour la visualiser.</span><script type='text/javascript'>
```

Code:
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/3?view=entry']
    page_number = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        mail=response.xpath("//span//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/@href").get()
        yield{
            'email':mail
        }
```

Comment: you have defined a class but you never instantiate it. Your code just loads a couple of libraries and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is static except `email` portion. That's why you are getting None. To grab the email, you can use scrapy with SeleniumRequest

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):

        yield SeleniumRequest(url='https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/3?view=entry', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        
        driver=response.meta['driver']
        r = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        yield {
            'mail_link': r.xpath('//*[@class="contact"]/following-sibling::div[1]/p/span/a/@href').get(),
            'mail': r.xpath('//*[@class="contact"]/following-sibling::div[1]/p/span/a/text()').get()
            
        }
```

**Output:**

```
{'mail_link': 'mailto:fzabdellatif@2MZA-avocats.com', 'mail': 'fzabdellatif@2MZA-avocats.com'}
```

You have to add the following code in `settings.py file`

```
# Middleware

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

# Selenium
from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
# '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--headless']
```

Comment: File "D:\sample\sample\spiders\test.py", line 1359, in parse
    driver=response.meta['driver']
KeyError: 'driver'

Comment: @Amen Aziz, I've updated

Comment: now they provide these error `raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://`

Comment: That may be your typo. Try to copy the url  from the code